# How do I change Table view of products into Side By Side View, like online shopping products list with HTML5 and CSS3 in MVC Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a list of movies where the data is coming from the database table. So I need to create the Side By Side view of products using @foreach(){ .... }. Please someone review my code below and help me get through this step.

I want my products as (using @foreach item):

Product 1       Product 2     Product 3

Product 4       Product 5     Product 6

I tried to do

```
         @foreach(var i=0; i< Model.Count; i+=2)
         {
         }
```

but didn't work maybe because of my images, which are coming from db as Imagepath.

```
 <table class="table">
     <tr>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MoviesName)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImgPath)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReYear)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitPrice)
         </th>
     </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MoviesName)
             </td>
             <td>
                 <img src="@Url.Content("~/Image/" + 
                  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.ImgPath))" alt="" 
                  width="75" , height="100" />
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReYear)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @String.Format("{0:c}", item.UnitPrice)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID 
                   }) |
                 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = 
                    item.MovieID 
                   }) |
                 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = 
                  item.MovieID 
                   })
            </td>
         </tr>
     }

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build a side-by-side layout, you'll need to choose either a `<div>` based or a `<table>` based layout.

`<div>` based is easiest as you can use a `@foreach` loop to build a `<div>`-based, side-by-side layout easily. For example, here's a super simple way of doing it using Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-4">...Build your product in here...</div>
    }
</div>
```

Or...you can make your layout using a `<table>`, but this is more complex; you'll need to use nested loops and a bit of math to get the rows and columns right. Here's one way to achieve this:

1. First, figure out how many rows there'll be based on `Model.Count` products:

   ```
   @{
       int columns = 3;
       int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(Model.Count / (float)columns);
   }
   ```
2. Next, setup nested loops similar to this:

   ```
   <table>
   @for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
   {
       <tr>
       @for (int column = 1; column <= columns; ++column)
       {
           @if ((row * columns) + column <= Model.Count)
           {
               <td>...Build your product in here...</td>
           }
           else
           {
               break;
           }
       }
       </tr>
   }
   </table>
   ```

Comment: Thank You so much. I appreciate your help. Worked beautifully.